# Without switching on, charger lights turns ON when phone gets connected?

Tags: samsung, charging

It's kinda bad day today as i dropped my phone into a water for 5 sec. Phone turned on & I tried to clean it.

Since the battery gets low, i plugged the charger cable to my phone. Without switching ON the charger, the light turns ON in Charger but the truth is i didn't switched ON.

What issue is this? Is my phone discharges the battery when something gets connected without Turning ON anything? Also, i can't charge the battery. Please help!

Comment: Seems like a short-circuit to me. If the charger is turned off but the phone shows that it is charging then it might be broken. If it actually works, try to dry it completely (by putting it near heater or similar) before turning on again. Also remove the battery to prevent another short-circuit.

Comment: @GiantTree Never ever the heater (or the sun, or – beware! – the microwave). Do as Yuva did: use rice! – And Yuva: Keep the battery out and the device disconnected until completely dried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think answering my own question will be helpful for other to easily to get.Right,the Solution is

> Keeping in an uncooked rice for some hours made phone to work.

As the comments to my question pointed out, definitely …

- avoid drying it with heat (e.g. in the sun, on a heater, or with a hairdryer)
- keep the battery out of the device during the "drying process" to avoid short-circuiting

Hope it helps others!